# How to get the continent given the coordinates (latitude and longitude) in Python?

Tags: python, python-requests, geolocation, coordinates, geopy

Is there a method that allows to get the continent where it is in place given its coordinates (without an API key)?

I'm using:

```py
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent='...')
location = geolocator.reverse('51.0456448, 3.7273618')
print(location.address)
print((location.latitude, location.longitude))
print(location.raw)
```

But it does not return the continent. Even giving a place name and using `geolocator.geocode()` doesn't work. Besides, even giving a name and using:

```py
import urllib.error, urllib.request, urllib.parse
import json

target = 'http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/json?' 

local = 'Paris'
url = target + urllib.parse.urlencode({'address': local, 'key' : 42})

data = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
js = json.loads(data)
print(json.dumps(js, indent=4))
```

Doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but for future reference and those who could need it, like me recently, here is one way to do it with Wikipedia and the use of [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/), [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [geopy](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/):

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

URLS = {
    "Africa": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sovereign_states_and_dependent_territories_in_Africa",
    "Asia": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sovereign_states_and_dependent_territories_in_Asia",
    "Europe": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sovereign_states_and_dependent_territories_in_Europe",
    "North America": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sovereign_states_and_dependent_territories_in_North_America",
    "Ocenia": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sovereign_states_and_dependent_territories_in_Oceania",
    "South America": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sovereign_states_and_dependent_territories_in_South_America",
}
```

```py
def get_continents_and_countries() -> dict[str, str]:
    """Helper function to get countries and corresponding continents.

    Returns:
        Dictionary where keys are countries and values are continents.

    """
    df_ = pd.concat(
        [
            pd.DataFrame(
                pd.read_html(
                    requests.get(url).text.replace("<br />", ";"),
                    match="Flag",
                )[0]
                .pipe(
                    lambda df_: df_.rename(
                        columns={col: i for i, col in enumerate(df_.columns)}
                    )
                )[2]
                .str.split(";;")
                .apply(lambda x: x[0])
            )
            .assign(continent=continent)
            .rename(columns={2: "country"})
            for continent, url in URLS.items()
        ]
    ).reset_index(drop=True)
    df_["country"] = (
        df_["country"]
        .str.replace("*", "", regex=False)
        .str.split("[")
        .apply(lambda x: x[0])
    ).str.replace("\xa0", "")
    return dict(df_.to_dict(orient="split")["data"])
```

```py
def get_location_of(coo: str, data: dict[str, str]) -> tuple[str, str, str]:
    """Function to get the country of given coordinates.

    Args:
        coo: coordinates as string ("lat, lon").
        data: input dictionary of countries and continents.

    Returns:
        Tuple of coordinates, country and continent (or Unknown if country not found).

    """
    geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="stackoverflow", timeout=25)
    country: str = (
        geolocator.reverse(coo, language="en-US").raw["display_name"].split(", ")[-1]
    )
    return (coo, country, data.get(country, "Unknown"))
```

Finally:

```py
continents_and_countries = get_continents_and_countries()

print(get_location_of("51.0456448, 3.7273618", continents_and_countries))

# Output
('51.0456448, 3.7273618', 'Belgium', 'Europe')
```